# Overlapping image in photoshop splice, how to float with CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-float

Here is the site I am working on:

http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera2012/test/home-pg.html

My problem is the red box in the top right corner.  I spliced up the site is photoshop but since that part overlaps I needed to split the image in 2.  How would I go about placing just the red box floating over everything else? z-depth maybe?

I would of course save it as a png to save transparency, but I wouldn't even know where to start to make it float over the existing 2 images

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `<td>` that contains your image (let's call it `<td class="imageholder">`):

```
td.imageholder { position: relative; }
```

From there, cenk's solution will work, regardless of the browser window.

**Explanation:**
Absolutely positioned elements look at their container element, which defaults to the entire document. If an absolutely positioned element is inside another element with position: absolute or relative, it will use that as the starting point for positioning.

Comment: hmm... Maybe I am doing that wrong, here is what I did

html:
<td class="imageholder"><img src="images/special.png" id="rightAligned"/></a></td>

css:
img#rightAligned {
   position: absolute;
   top: 47px;
   right: 192px;
}
td.imageholder { 
 position: relative;
}

Comment: Could you update the live example with your new code so we can look at it?

Comment: I just realized this is not working in FireFox... Why would that be?

http://graves-incorporated.com/test_sites/solera_new/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start:

HTML

```
   <img src="your-transparent-file.png" id="rightAligned"/>
```

CSS

```
img#rightAligned {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50px; // adjust
   right: 20px; // adjust
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  That works until I re size the browser.  Is there any way to lock it into that exact position??

Comment: Well, that depends. In order to fix an element to a position use "position: fixed" instead.